# Search for text in excel sheet and extract range of cells to a table

Tags: excel, vba, range, copy-paste

Regularly I have to extract some data from excel sheets. Most of the time the sheet is small enough to do this per hand, which means, looking for a specific string and manually copy-paste the cells of interest.

[Example of an excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4uaa.png)

This time I have a file with more than 5000 lines, which prevents me to do this as usual. This is a good occasion to write a simple code to do that automatically. The best way to do this in my case would be to:

- 1) Look for the cells containing the term "text"
- 2) For each cell:

  - 2.1) Select a range of cells
  - 2.2) Copy the range of cells and paste it to this destination range

As I am not used to code, I search on internet some code with similar behaviour. What I found so far is a code for the 1) step. In the following code, the addresses of the cells are written in a destination range:

```
Dim findWhat As String, address As String
Dim fsr As Range, rs As Range, fCount As Long

findWhat = InputBox("Enter what you want to find?", "Find what...")

If Len(findWhat) > 0 Then
    'clearFinds
    Set frs = Range("A1:AW6000")
    Set rs = frs.Find(What:=findWhat)
    If Not rs Is Nothing Then
        address = rs.address
        Do
            Range("bb1").Offset(fCount).Value = rs.Value
            Range("bc1").Offset(fCount).Value = rs.address
            Set rs = frs.FindNext(rs)
            fCount = fCount + 1
        Loop While Not rs Is Nothing And rs.address <> address
    End If
End If
```

Regarding the step 2.1), I know that I have to implement this to select a range for each cell found in the step 1):

```
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(4, 9))
```

Finally, I planned to use the following code for the step 2.2):

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D4").Copy _ 
    destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E5")
```

Despite my efforts, I don´t know how to code that properly to make this code working. Could someone give me a little help?

Comment: Are you looking for your specific value in a certain column? Or all columns?

Comment: If I'm correct, you want to find a certain word, and from that word copy everything 4 cells down, and 9 cells to the right, onto another sheet. And do that for every word found? Do you just need the text in these cells, or all the formatting and the like as well?

Comment: @JvdV I am looking for a specific text in all columns

Comment: @Plutian I do not need to create another sheet for every word found, but rather a "global" destination range, like a destination table

Comment: Well, in that case your `FindNext` approach is looking quite allright. Now the difference with `ActiveCell` from your step 2.1 is that `Find` actually sets a `Range` object. In your case `rs`. So try to work from there using `Offset`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You might need to adjust the destination range to suit.

Also check the `Find` parameters; in particular, are you looking for cells containing just the text entered in the input box or could cells contain other text (adjust `lookat`).

The `Resize` bit says copy a range of 5 rows by 10 columns where the top left cell is the one containing the found text.

```
Sub x()

Dim findWhat As String, s As String
Dim rs As Range, frs as Range

findWhat = InputBox("Enter what you want to find?", "Find what...")

If Len(findWhat) > 0 Then
    'clearFinds
    Set frs = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AW6000")
    Set rs = frs.Find(What:=findWhat, Lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not rs Is Nothing Then
        s = rs.address
        Do
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(5, 10).Value = rs.Resize(5, 10).Value
            Set rs = frs.FindNext(rs)
        Loop While rs.address <> s
    End If
End If

End Sub
```